# Runtime Error 3134 - Syntax Error in INSERT INTO Statement (MS Access VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I changed the input on the data table and added the "from" and "to" to the table and the query, however now I get the error

> Runtime Error 3134 - Syntax Error in INSERT INTO Statement

My statement:

```
db.Execute "INSERT INTO Temp ( LoadNum, ReferenceNum, ActivityDate, Appointment, From, To, OriginCity, OriginCountry, DestinationCity, DestinationCountry, [Carrier Name], [Load Status] ) " _
                & "SELECT Data.LoadNum, Data.ReferenceNum, Data.ActivityDate, Data.Appointment, Data.From, Data.To, Data.OriginCity, Data.OriginCountry, Data.DestinationCity, Data.DestinationCountry, Data.[Carrier Name], Data.[Load Status] " _
                & "FROM Data " _
                & "WHERE [Data].[CarrierCode]='" & cNum & "';"
```

I've been staring at this for a while, but i cannot find the error. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you take a moment to apply style formatting to your codes? http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Syntax Error is usually just a typo in your query. I have had this probem many times. The best procedure is to start with a very simple version of the query and then adding the other parts step by step while trying it out everytime. This way you can pinpoint the probelematic part.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need wrap at least these reserved words in brackets:

```
.., [From], [To], ..
```

Full list:
[Reserved words in Access SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: This was exactly the issue! Is there an overview online to know what the reserved words within VBA are?

Comment: Yes. Just bing for it.